# How does BPs recover from critical failures while producing?

Tags: nodeos

I'm wondering how BPs recover from critical failures while many BPs are broken, what is the process?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the current 21 block producer is failing, the next one back it up, if more and more began to fail there is 100+ block producer behind to take this role if needed
edit: in fact ( for now ) they gonna have to unregister themself to allow another one to take his place